# How do you obtain the click share data on Google Ads API?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, adgroup

How do you obtain the click share data on Google Ads API?

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v8/ad_group?hl=en

When you see this Google Ads API, it states that 'There's metrics that you can't use ad_group with FROM. ' The click share falls under this and we don't know how to obtain the data. Anyone have any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

You could try their query in this [query builder](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v8/ad_group_query_builder?hl=en) provided by Google.

From my experience, you can't query some field together. My guess is some fields are like group by in SQL so there is no way you can query both at once. Using the query builder, you could find out which field are exclusive to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Click share is only available in the "campaign" resource as metrics.search_click_share.